# Javascript, create an array from values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to emulate his:

```
"someArray" => array:3 [▼
    0 => "3"
    1 => "17"
    2 => "21"
  ]
```

But I'm getting:

```
  "myArray" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "3,17,21"
  ]
```

I'm doing:

```
var optionsChecked = [];
optionsChecked.push($(this).val());
console.log(optionsChecked);
```

I need to get what I write first

Answer (score 0):

You can use the spread operator after `split()`

```
optionsChecked.push(...$(this).val().split(','));
```